# How to check if a row has odd number?

Tags: wpf, xaml, multidatatrigger

I'm trying to set different color for odd rows using XAML.

The datagrid in question has 3 different types of data, which I want to color differently, and simply changing AlternatingRowBackground won't do.

I'm planning on using something like

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>                         
         <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/> 
         <Condition Binding="{Binding IsOddRow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>      
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDFE6ED"/>                   
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

There doesn't seem to be such a property as `IsOddRow`. What property should I check instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can set `AlternationCount` on the `DataGrid` and then bind to the ancestor `DataGridRows` attached property `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex`. If the value is "1" you have an odd row number.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
          AlternationCount="2">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                     Path=IsSelected}"
                                   Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                                                     Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
                                   Value="1"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDFE6ED"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <!-- ... -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```

*Note that when binding to an attached property, you must put parentheses around the attached property. `Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)` will work but `Path=ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` won't.*

---

**Update**
You could also create the property `IsOddRow` through an attached behavior. In the behavior you subscribe to `LoadingRow`. In the event handler you get the index for the loaded row and check if it is odd or not. The result is then stored in an attached property called `IsOddRow` which you can bind to.

To start the behavior add `behaviors:DataGridBehavior.ObserveOddRow="True"` to the `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
          behaviors:DataGridBehavior.ObserveOddRow="True">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(behaviors:DataGridBehavior.IsOddRow),
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDFE6ED"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

*DataGridBehavior*

```
public class DataGridBehavior
{
    #region ObserveOddRow

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObserveOddRowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ObserveOddRow",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(DataGridBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnObserveOddRowChanged));
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(DataGrid))]
    public static bool GetObserveOddRow(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        return (bool)dataGrid.GetValue(ObserveOddRowProperty);
    }
    public static void SetObserveOddRow(DataGrid dataGrid, bool value)
    {
        dataGrid.SetValue(ObserveOddRowProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnObserveOddRowChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = target as DataGrid;
        dataGrid.LoadingRow += (object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e2) =>
        {
            DataGridRow dataGridRow = e2.Row;
            bool isOddRow = dataGridRow.GetIndex() % 2 != 0;
            SetIsOddRow(dataGridRow, isOddRow);
        };
    }

    #endregion // ObserveOddRow

    #region IsOddRow

    public static DependencyProperty IsOddRowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsOddRow",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(DataGridBehavior),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(false));
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(DataGridRow))]
    public static bool GetIsOddRow(DataGridRow dataGridCell)
    {
        return (bool)dataGridCell.GetValue(IsOddRowProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsOddRow(DataGridRow dataGridCell, bool value)
    {
        dataGridCell.SetValue(IsOddRowProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion // IsOddRow
}
```

Comment: If the control is the standard DataGrid, then this is a better approach than mine (no need for a value converter).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which grid/row type you are using, so I can't give you the exact property names, however, bind to the row's index (row number) and use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) (that returns true) to check if the row is odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every answer use `AlternationCount="2"` but I find it a little bit too limiting. On my side I use something like `AlternationCount="{ Binding MainData.ProjColl.Count}"` in order to number my rows until the end ( take care it starts at 0 ! ).

In this case I need a value Converter as mentioned by @Danny Varod.

I use the converter to alternate the color of the rows ( nearly answering the question )

```cs
public class IsEvenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool res = false;
        int? val = value as int?;
        if (null != val)
            res = (0 == (val % 2));
        return res;
    }     
    ...
}
```

And the calling XAML

```
<UserControl ...
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <vm_nmspc:IsEvenConverter x:Key="IsEven"/>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>

        <!--Converter will be used below-->

        <Style.Triggers>
            ...
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                            Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                                            Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsEven}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MainData.ProjColl}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AlternationCount="{ Binding MainData.ProjColl.Count}" >
    ...
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project Name" .... 

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and some discrete screenshots

[image]
[image]

Another part of the same code:
[Simple way to display row numbers on WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661998)