# How to have alternative background color of the selected rows on WPF DataGrid via MultiDataTrigger

Tags: wpf, datagrid, multidatatrigger

I would like to display the odd vs. even selected rows with different background color (gray) in a WPF `DataGrid`. I already use the `RowBackground="#DDD"`, `AlternatingRowBackground="#EEE"` and `AlternationCount=2` properties withing `DataGrid` itself to alternate the color of non-selected rows.

I've already browsed many threads on StackOverflow, but can't find why the `Style.Triggers` has no effect. I use this [attached property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968338/how-to-check-if-a-row-has-odd-number) to determine whether it is an odd or even row.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        
        <!-- Changes the row style template to have more advanced "borders" (dotted, dashed, etc.) based on value converters -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Setter>
        
        <!-- Changes the background color of odd rows (will do the same for even one with a slightly different color) -->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                               Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding (behaviors:DataGridBehavior.IsOddRow), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                               Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="LightYellow"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <!-- Same principle for even rows -->
            <!-- ... -->

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Same (no) effect if I use only one `Condition` in the `MutliDataTrigger`.

Thanks for any insights :-)

Comment: I eventually followed the first example base on `<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">...` with the default attached property `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` which works well. Still need to think about the `<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use a custom behavior for this, you can use the built-in alternation mechanism.

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2"
          ...>
   <!-- ...other properties -->
</DataGrid>
```

Create a style for `DataGridRow` with triggers for the `IsSelected` and [`AlternationIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.alternationindex?view=netcore-3.1) attached property. Note, that we have to set the row background color and the alternating background color here, too, because setting the [`RowBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc189288(v=vs.95)) and [`AlternatingRowBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc189381(v=vs.95)) on `DataGrid` will overwrite the background values defined in the style and the selection highlighting would not work, so remove them from `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">

      <!-- Changes the row style template to have more advanced "borders" (dotted, dashed, etc.) based on value converters -->
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <!-- ... -->
      </Setter>

      <!-- Part for odd rows. -->
      <Style.Triggers>
         <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                          Value="False"/>
               <Condition Property="AlternationIndex"
                          Value="1"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
               <Setter Property="Background"
                       Value="#EEE"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
         </MultiTrigger>

         <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                          Value="True"/>
               <Condition Property="AlternationIndex"
                          Value="1"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
               <Setter Property="Background"
                       Value="Yellow"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
         </MultiTrigger>

         <!-- Part for even rows. -->

         <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                          Value="False"/>
               <Condition Property="AlternationIndex"
                          Value="0"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
               <Setter Property="Background"
                       Value="#DDD"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
         </MultiTrigger>

         <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                          Value="True"/>
               <Condition Property="AlternationIndex"
                          Value="0"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
               <Setter Property="Background"
                       Value="LightYellow"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
         </MultiTrigger>

      </Style.Triggers>

   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Since a `DataGridCell` is a child of a `DataGridRow`, the selection colors defined there will occlude the row colors. To avoid creating the same style for `DataGridCell`, too, we set its background transparent when it is selected.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                      Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Transparent"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Yes, it is far better to use the easiest and most straightforward solution. I added your code into mine, but it leads to an error (I don't think it is something hard to debug, but will do it later). I'm also interested in coloring the rows with (still) another different color when the mouse is over them. I have no doubt that your example provides a way to achieve it more easily :-)