# WPF DataGrid numbering

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061013/how-to-show-row-number-in-first-column-of-wpf-datagrid); the solution gives me one row too much. I have three items in my ItemsSource but I get four rows in the grid, last one has index 4 and all columns are empty. Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `CanUserAddRows=false` on `<Datagrid />`

The last row is the "new row" where you can enter in a new piece of data

Comment: Didn't try this because I solved this by manually adding the index column in my viewmodel. But I believe that this is correct answer.