# Show Index of each element of an CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a View and a Viewmodel.

The Viewmodel has a property of type `ICollectionView` which I instance a `CollectionViewSource` with the Source, which is an `ObservableCollection<Foo>`

Now on my view I have a Datagrid to show this info, and in my Datagrid.Columns I have a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, inside a `DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate` and then a `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`

Now inside my cell template for my 1st header, I want to show the index or element number of each element of my collection, the cell template is like this:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path= DataContext.CurrentPosition}"></TextBlock>
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Now my `DataContext.CurrentPosition` returns empty, I dont know if this is the correct property of the object to return the index.

Comment: Are you refering to [this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.currentposition?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_ICollectionView_CurrentPosition)? If this is the case, then you can only get the index of the current element of the `CollectionViewSource` itself and not get the individual index of each element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the issue by following Andy's answer in this thread: [How to show row-number in first column of WPF Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061013/how-to-show-row-number-in-first-column-of-wpf-datagrid)