# Grid layout with visible row numbers and column nimbers

Tags: silverlight

How do i display the row number and column number for a grid layout in silverlight?I do not find any property in the grid which does it for me.

Comment: What's a grid layout? Do you mean the `Grid` panel, the `DataGrid` control, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661998/simple-way-to-display-row-numbers-on-wpf-datagrid):

> One way is to add them in the LoadingRow event for the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" ...

void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString(); 
}
```

Or another approach using multibinding and a converter is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041168/how-to-show-row-index-for-wpf-toolkit-datagrid/2045607#2045607).

Comment: I meant GRID layout.Sorry if my question was not clear.I want to customize the grid lines and display them along with row and column numbers

Comment: Ah sorry, I presumed you meant a Datagrid. I'm not sure it's possible to bind to the row number in a layout grid (and googling didn't bring anything up). If you could adapt your XAML to use a GridView or ListView, they do would have row numbers to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create a grid with 20 columns and 20 rows...

```
    Dim newGrid As New Grid 'Or use existing grid

    For x = 1 To 20
        'Create row numbers
        Dim rowNum As New TextBlock With {.Text = x}
        Grid.SetColumn(rowNum, 0)
        Grid.SetRow(rowNum, x)
        newGrid.Children.Add(rowNum)
        'Create column numbers
        Dim colNum As New TextBlock With {.Text = x}
        Grid.SetColumn(colNum, x)
        Grid.SetRow(colNum, 0)
        newGrid.Children.Add(colNum)
    Next

    'Create 20 columns and 20 rows (plus one each for numbers)
    For x = 0 To 20
        newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(New RowDefinition With {.Height = New GridLength(20)})
        newGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(New ColumnDefinition With {.Width = New GridLength(20)})
    Next
```

Of course you would have to play with things like alignments and maybe you want to put some borders in there or something so you can see the rows and columns... numbers on the top and left are hard to line up without the lines there.

You can add row and column numbers to existing grids, you just have to make sure you don't have any of your actual content in column 0 or row 0, which you'll be using for the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:) I did something similar and it worked :)